Car side-mirror dimmer simulator circuit - DIY
Would like to make a simple car side-mirror simulator circuit. The side mirrors I installed (for better blind spot) do not have a dimmer circuit and I am getting LIN bus errors since the dimmer wires are disconnected. Would like to DIY something that fools the car into thinking it is connected. Needs to be small, not much bigger than a coin or bottle cap.
Only need to DIY the area with the red circle.
Not sure what the values are in the reference design example:

Seems R1 is 3.9 Ohm (watts?)
Seems R2 is 3.3 Ohms (watts?)
C1 is 2.1F??? (assuming 16V to 50V)

What I was able to research is that I need something that is:

Max current 400mA
Operating current 150mA
Voltage max 1.4V, although reference design shows 12V going to it
About 1F in capacitance
has shunt resistors
the actual mirror with dimmer reads 100 Ohm when discharged

Here is a design reference example:
Texas Instruments Automotive Auto-dimming Mirror Driver Reference Design
PS: the best way would be to send LIN messages that says the dimer is there, but do not have the time to dive deep into deciphering/isolating LIN messages


The document you linked tells you "Electrically, the electrochromic mirror
behaves like a very large capacitor, typically greater than 1 F, as well as a small shunt resistance". Beyond that, I don't see what your actual question is.

I would like to establish the component values for that circuit marked with red.  Looks like 3.9 Ohm and 3.3 Ohm shunt resistors.  I assume 1/4 watt is ok?  There is 12V car voltage going to it, so do not want to short it out.   And I cannot figure the capacitor C1 value, it's labeled as 2.1 or 21?   A 1F capacitor would be hard to find, and too large. the size of a soda can.

It doesn't have 12V going to it, it's driven by a circuit that operates from a 12V supply. The values seem reasonable but we don't have a better diagram than you do so it's impossible to say for sure. If R1 has 1.4V across it it will dissipate half a watt so I'd suggest a 1W resistor at least.

I thought the T2 transistor is turned on by U1 and that sends the 12V from V1 to the mirror dimming circuit comprised of C1, R1, R2?  What value do you think C1 is?

T2 is an emitter follower so the voltage going to that circuit will be about 0.7V lower than the output of U1, and that's powered from 3.3V so its output can never be higher than that.

Thank you.  What capacitor size do you think C1 is then?

I forgot that I had a cheap Chinese capacitor measurement device.  This is what I got for the OEM dimming mirror:  57.47 mF, ESR= 39 Ohm, Vloss=  30%
